# In Memoriam: Peter Schickele

Tags: discussion, in-memoriam

[Peter Schickele](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peter_Schickele) died at home at the age of 88. While most people were familiar with him as the ostensible chronicler of P.D.Q. Bach's compositions, he also composed the score for science fiction film *[Silent Running](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silent_Running)*, among other professional musical work that was overshadowed by his parodies/pastiches.

https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLys18dU1NHZPwt8Cq7JV1hnZ6TkVkVbA7

Answer (score 4):

As a child, I attended many P. D. Q. Bach concerts, whenever his tour came to town.  As a teen, I also saw went to one of his much more serious concerts, where he presented a much more balanced mix of his compositions, jokes, and other material, which was also fun to attend.

Beyond his excellent score for *Silent Running* (which he discussed in detail several times on his public radio show), I remember his connection to fantasy and science fiction as the narrator for the original short film reading of *Where the Wild Things Are*.

Answer (score 3):

Sorry to hear that. I met him once--we have the same alma mater, and he played a concert there while I was a current student, some 25 years ago. I presented him with a homemade instrument which he very graciously accepted. He must have already been in his 60s then!

Answer (score 2):

I got his music (so long ago it must have been vinyl) as a birthday gift.